# User entered apssword required on API call in aem

Tags: java, aem

We have a requirement in which we have a page to show to the end user. On click of submit button on the page,an OSGI service is getting called which further calls an API. 
The issue we are facing is that we are not allowed to store the API password anywhere and can only be entered by the permitted person. The challenge is:

> 1. We do not have any user interface to enable such thing.
> 2. What we could think of is getting the password entered in console during AEM startup but not aware how this is possible and everytime
>      any of the multiple instances is restarted, we will need to call the
>      permitted person to enter the password.

Can anybody provide his/her inputs on achieving this.

Comment: is the password end user specific, or same for all users?

Comment: What do you mean by "permitted person"? Is this the end user or someone else who is managing the configuration?

Comment: This is not the end user. It is the person who will be having the API password.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to question the requirement:

- AEM works best with staticky rendered pages delivered from the dispatcher
- personalised content requires therefore extra effort

But it can be achieved nonetheless:

- you could deliver a static page and render the personalised information about the user via JavaScript and retrieve it via servlet call.

In case you need to store the password, you could create an OSGi bundle which is deployed and started when an instance is started. Usually you can achieve this by packaging it via content package and put it into an install folder: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToInstallPackagesUsingRepositoryInstall.html

The dispatcher must be configured to not cache this page though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly then you are not permitted to store the api password in the AEM console. Can you store it in the server away from the AEM instance? If yes then you can create a file like a properties file and store it in the server and read the same file from you service before making the api call.

Comment: Yes, we proposed this but saving the password anywhere is not allowed. Also, the password would be changed every 90 days, hence the team managing the passwords would only have the updated passwords and nobody apart from them can have the passwords.

Comment: Password can be updated by a cron job that will run every 90 days to update the password but then you are not allowed to store the password. Then you can build a OSGI service that before the API call will get the password and pass it to the service thats calling the actual API.